# Prolog: Recursive function redefinition

Tags: prolog, operation

Is there a way to "recursively redefine" (don't know the technical term) prolog predicates?

Consider these predicates:

```
f(X,Y,A):-A is Y xor X.
arity(f,2).
```

now i want to automatically create 2 new predicates f1/2 and f2/1 with the following definition:

```
f1(Y,A):-f(1,Y,A).
f2(A):-f1(1,A).
```

So the predicate should get a (binary) function as input and creates new predicates by filling the function's parameters (# defined through arity) from left to right with 1.

Is this possible? I tried various combinations of the univ operator and call() but nothing succeded.

Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would really be appreciated.

**Edit: An example for a higher arity:**

```
f(W,X,Y,Z,A):-A is Y xor X xor W xor Z.
arity(f,4).
```

-->

```
f1(X,Y,Z,A):-f(1,X,Y,Z,A).
f2(Y,Z,A):-f1(1,Y,Z,A).
f3(Z,A):-f2(1,Z,A).
f4(A):-f3(1,A).
```

Since I'm only interrested in the return value of f (A) with all parameters set to 1 there might be an easier way to do this...
Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by what you're after. Can you give an example of a higher arity? Also, do you want the new predicates to be added to the prolog database for immediate use, or do you want just write them out to a text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [term_expansion/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_expansion%2F2), it can modify the program arbitrarily when it is read by the compiler.

Though be careful, this is a powerful feature and you can easily make a big confusing mess.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite get your question, but maybe this could be helpful:

```
t :-
    assert(my_add(A,B,C):-C is A+B),
    my_add(1,2,R),
    writeln(R).
```

test:

```
?- t.
3
true.
```